# How to check 20,000 Twitter Accounts for activity? (are inactive)

Tags: twitter

I'm writing a little app to remove inactive twitter accounts from my follow list.

I currently follow 20,000 people.

I'm looking at [the GET statuses/public_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline) API call, which I could use to get the timeline of each person I follow and if their last post is from > 30 days ago, I could "unfollow" them.

However, this is a rate-limited call, so I believe I will run afoul of twitter's API limit. Is there a better / more clever way to implement this? Probably with a different call?

Comment: "I currently follow 20,000 people" - sleep much?

Comment: It probably took a while to follow 20,000 people, perhaps it'll take a while to unfollow the ones who have given up on twittering.

Comment: I usually friend people who @ me. Coming back to bite me.

Comment: Also, @pst if you are going to edit the title of my question, please at least spell correctly. You are making me look like an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the streaming API:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api

You simply filter your query by userid and check the date of the last post. Plus, it is not rate limited.

Comment: streaming API won't work for 20k ID's. The limit is 5k. Look into GNIP - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers. Let me know if you want me to make it into an answer.

Comment: Well, since it's an operation that he probably has to do only once, he can split up the IDs in 4 groups and run the program four times, each time with a different group. IMHO, it's better than paying actual money for something you can do for free.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your limited by account. Each account is only able to track 5k.